# Blank page using python with selenium on real estate website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I often use Selenium and for the first time today I have this problem where I see a page that remains blank when Selenium accesses the site (using my browser manually instead everything goes perfectly), I'm afraid it's a sort of anti-bot protection, also If this has never happened to me, does anyone know how to fix it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

driver_path = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_path, options=options)

website=f'https://www.realestate.com.au/property/14-kelso-st-aitkenvale-qld-4814/'

driver.get(website)

time.sleep(20)
```